# $\Bbb C/(1+ib)\Bbb Z$ is an elliptic curve

Tags: elliptic-curves, riemann-surfaces

I have to prove that $\Bbb C/(1+ib)\Bbb Z$ is an elliptic curve, where $b\in\{1,2,3\}$.
The problem is that the teacher was a bit broad giving the definition of elliptic curve.
He presented them as tori like $\Bbb C/\Lambda$ where $\Lambda=\omega_1\Bbb Z+\omega_2\Bbb Z$ is a lattice.

Now,$(1+ib)\Bbb Z$ is not a lattice and the space $\Bbb C/(1+ib)\Bbb Z$ can be seen as $\{0\le\Im z<b\}$ indetifying the upper and lower lines $\Im z=0$ and $\Im z=b$ respectively, getting an infinite cylinder.
Even identifying the point at infinity, it doesn't sound good.

Hints?

Comment: Are you sure he doesn't mean $\Bbb C/(\Bbb Z+ib\Bbb Z)$?

Comment: Definitely. Your object was already discussed in the same exercise.
And he pointed out that "this elliptic curve may be different from $\Bbb C/\Lambda$"

Comment: It might be time to ask the teacher for the full and precise definition of elliptic curve, for if the definition is "it's something like XYZ" and the homework problem says "this one might not be like XYZ", then it's pretty tough to do anything reasonable. In short, this isn't a problem that MSE can help you solve -- it's a *communication* problem rather than a math problem.

Comment: I have many communication problems with this teacher. Moreover he's away and I have to complete this work within this weekend. I simply hoped that someone experienced here could see my doubt and his skills allow him/her to interpretate the problem and finally help me.